# How to fix Amadeus API 500 Internal Error?

Tags: amadeus

The "Flight Offers Search V2" and "Flight Offers Price V1" endpoints are returning errors. Probably it's a configuration issue

[image: API Errors]

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far? A snippet of your code/attempt will help users of StackOverflow help you.

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for reaching out. I fixed the problem. Apparently, in their  documentation, it said X-HTTP-Method-override should be GET. That's not working. It should be POST

Comment: I will mark this as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Flight Offers Search API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference) comes with 2 different endpoints:

- GET with a limited number of parameters but easier to implement for the most common use cases
- POST version much more complete offering all types of filtering but it requires to build the JSON body. In that context we use a POST to offer the possibility to build the JSON body without length restriction, even if it is for a search. That's why in the swagger documentation you will find `X-HTTP-Method-Override` set at `GET`.

The [Flight Offers Price API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-price/api-reference) is built from the response of `Flight Offers Search`. To allow developers to reuse the body of the previous response we created this endpoint using the verb POST, That's why in the swagger documentation you will find `X-HTTP-Method-Override` set at `GET`.

Comment: Thank you Anthony

Comment: hey anthony im still in the dark about this, could you help?