# Receiving an Internal Server : 500 error when trying to hit Amadeus for Master Price Travel Board Search

Tags: c#, .net, amadeus

Trying to get a response after making a request to the Amadeus server for Air>>Search & Shopping>>Master Price Travel Board Search. But eventually getting a 500 Internal server error.

Also tried Anthony's way of setting the Header Value to GET in [How to fix Amadeus API 500 Internal Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146870/how-to-fix-amadeus-api-500-internal-error)

But still getting the same exception.

Comment: Which API are you using? Flight Low-fare Search or Flight Offers Search? Are you trying to call the API through the portal or using your own code? Which parameters do you use? Can you share the Request and the Response you get?

Comment: 1. The API I am using is the "Master Price Travel Board Search" which comes under Enterprise API's>>Search & Shopping.2.

Comment: This API is part of the Enterprise framework. You need to contact your account manager to get dedicated support about this.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the assist, Anthony!